# iOS App Memory Limit

Tags: ios, memory-management

I wrote an iphone app that as a first function allows the user to download files. The user then manipulates these files in a particular way that wants them to be in memory.

It's not necessary that all of the files the user gets are in memory, just a few at a time that are well within memory constraints. However, the option to download the rest later is not available because of location assumptions (mainly that there is no assumption the user will be within wifi or data reception).

Is there a way around this? One example would be to have some sort of permanent write that I could access. Is that how the file storage apps solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you just storing everything as an array/dictionary/set/whatever currently? Without knowing more, I'd recommend CoreData. Create a model, move everything to more permanent storage, access whenever necessary.

Comment: Yes, currently, the files get downloaded to an NSDictionary. CoreData looks great. Thanks for that recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

Could you use a server to do the manipulation instead of the app?  iphone app sends the link to the server, server does the manipulation, and the the iphone downloads the manipulated link.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to keep access to the server then?

Comment: Yes.  But how would this work otherwise?  You need a connection to fetch the image to work with, right?